# how to specify multiple parameters in path react-route-dom 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

tell me how in version 6 of the route - pass several values ​​​​to path in version 5 this could be done through an array

```
 <Routes>
           {token
               ?
              <Route path={'chat'} element={<Chat/>}/>
               :
             <Route path={'/'} element={<Login/>}/>}
   </Routes>
```

Comment: Multiple route match params in a path, or multiple paths that render the same component? Can you provide an example for what you are trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Multiple paths that render the same component?

Comment: Sure, when we specified the path in version 5 - there it was possible to specify in path={['/', '/login']} and iterate so that two paths work for this page - and in version 6 specify only one value in path={ '/'} or path={'/login'}

i need to do like in version 5

Comment: Sorry, I meant example code for the routes you want multiple paths for, I understand the use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` component's `path` prop takes only a single string path value, not an array like previous versions did.

[Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactElement | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string; // <-- string type only
> }
> ```

You will need to render individual routes for each path.

Example:

```
<Route path='/' element={<Login />} />
<Route path='/home' element={<Login />} />
<Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
```

Or abstract this utility into a ***function*** (*not a component!*) It needs to be a function call as only `Route` or `React.Fragment` components are valid children of the `Routes` component.

```
const renderPaths = (paths, Element) =>
  paths.map((path) => <Route key={path} path={path} element={Element} />);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  {renderPaths(["/", "/home", "/login"], <Login />)}
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-add-multiple-path-for-home-page-with-react-router-dom-6 (forked)]